# What does $P(X\ge Y)$ mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, random-variables, poisson-distribution, binomial-distribution

**This is from Joseph Blitzstein, Introduction to Probability, pg 197, Question 20**:

> Let $X\sim \text{Bin}(100, 0.9)$.
>
> For each of the following parts, construct an example showing
> that it is possible, or explain clearly why it is impossible. In this problem, $Y$ is a random variable on the same probability space as $X$; note that $X$ and $Y$ are not necessarily
> independent.
>
> (a) Is it possible to have $Y\sim \text{Pois}(0.01)$ with $P(X \ge Y ) = 1$?

**I would like to know what does $P(X \ge Y)$ mean in this context. Does it mean that for all values that $X$ and $Y$ take $P(X \ge Y) = 1$?**

Comment: it's the probability of the set $\{\omega \in \Omega \mid X(\omega) \geq Y(\omega)\}$ for your question, what does it gives you for the repartition functions? And it is not for all values, just the set where it doesn't happens is neglectable

Comment: What do you mean by $Pois(0,0.01)$? The poisson distribution only takes in one parameter.

Comment: @julio_es_sui_glace So does this mean, both X and Y need to operate on the SAME outcome in the sample space?

Comment: By definition of real random variable on a probability space $\Omega$ they do. Maybe rework the definitions and construction of probability theory, and when you "fully" understand it, do this exercise again

Comment: @Julius - the question seems to have been edited, which now allows a simple intuitive answer by considering the possible values of $X$ and $Y$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$X$ and $Y$ are random variables, and $P(X \ge Y)$ is the probability that $X$ is greater than or equal to $Y$.  In this case your random variables are discrete, so if that probability is $1$, it does mean that $x$ is always  than or equal to $y$ for all possible values $(x,y)$ of the pair $(X,Y)$.

Further hint: what are the possible values of $X$?  What are the possible values of $Y$?

Comment: When you say "for all possible values $(x,y)$", I presume you mean for all possible pairs of values $(x,y)$ *with positive probability* (since this is a discrete distribution)

Comment: I am a little confused.

 In the comments to my post above, @julio_es_sui_glac says "it's the probability of the set {ω∈Ω∣X(ω)≥Y(ω)}
 for your question, what does it gives you for the repartition functions? And it is not for all values, just the set where it doesn't happens is neglectable."

So, both X and Y are function that map the SAME OUTCOME to some real value, right?

Comment: @Henry Yes: "possible" (in the discrete context) refers to events that have positive probability.

Comment: Yes, $\Omega$ is the sample space, the set of all possible outcomes.  $X$ and $Y$ are functions on the sample space, i.e. the outcome determines the values of the random variables.  I don't know what @julio_es_sui_glace means by "repartition function".

Comment: @RobertIsrael: Sorry, you seem to have missed the question. I probably was not clear enough. 

Can X and Y map different outcomes to real values, when X and Y are being compared or do X and Y need to map the SAME outcomes to real values when they are being compared, i.e X>=Y?

Comment: When you write $X \ge Y$ you are comparing the values of $X$ and $Y$ on the same outcome.

Comment: @S_M The Blitzstein book does not use $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$ styled [probability spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space) but if it did then the question would be whether it is possible to have $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega \in \Omega: X(\omega)\ge Y(\omega)\})=1$ so a comparison on the sample space, i.e. the set of outcomes.  Each individual $\omega$ would be an outcome

Comment: Thank you, everyone. Grateful!